# Which Collections types are Covariant and Contravariant in C# and VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, collections, covariance, contravariance

Ok, I know that IEnumerable is covariant. But outside of that one, I'm not sure which other ones are covariant and contravariant. The only way I can think to figure it out is to go through each and every type and look at the definition. I think it would be better to have them listed and memorized.  I've looked online but I've not found such a list.

Thanks!

Comment: You looking for something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_4)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. There is also IReadOnlyCollection(Of T), IReadOnlyList(Of T), and IReadOnlyDictionary(Of TKey, TValue). These are not listed on the page above.